# binding dynamic img in vuejs does not work for me

Tags: vue.js

I have a dynamic img being pulled from an api using vue.js.   For some strange reason, the image won't bind. I have tried both :src. and :attr but neither works. The url does display in the vue console inside of the data but can't get the image to display on the page. any help will go a long way.

```html
<html>
<head>
    <style></style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div id="editor">
      <img v-bind:src="PictureURL" />      
    </div>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.0.3/dist/vue.js"></script>
  <script>
    new Vue({
      el: "#editor",
      data: {    
        PictureUrl: "",
      },
      created: function() {
        this.getCurrentUser();
      },
      methods: {
        getCurrentUser: function() {
          var root = 'https://example.com';
          var headers = {
            accept: "application/json;odata=verbose"
          }
          var vm = this;
          var __REQUESTDIGEST = '';
          $.ajax({
            url: root + "_api/Properties",
            type: 'Get',
            headers: headers,
            success: function(data) {
              vm.PictureUrl = data.d.PictureUrl;
            }
          })
        },
      }
    })
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `<img v-bind:src="PictureURL" />` to `<img v-bind:src="PictureUrl" />`, so that you match the data item name. Vue should be giving you an error in the console about this.

Comment: can you tell me whats different--I cannot see

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/kch7sfda/

Example here.

You can try to:
 1. add `v-if` to img element
 2. rename `PictureUrl` to `pictureUrl` (first lowercase letter)

Comment: @emils Gulbis why would "P" need to be lowercased? I tried both and still doesn't work